# C++ Boost::bind: a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind

I would like to do something like

```
template<typename InstanceType>
            void add_test(void (InstanceType::* test_method )(void*),
 std::tr1::shared_ptr<InstanceType> user_test_case)
            {
                boost::function<void ()> op;
                op = boost::bind<InstanceType>(test_method, *user_test_case);
```

But it says:

```
1>d:\boost\boost/bind/mem_fn.hpp(359): error: a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function
1>          return (t.*f_);
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: It compiles in g++4.4 with     `#include<boost/bind.hpp>
    #include<boost/function.hpp>
    #include <tr1/memory>` and boost_1_54_0

Comment: boost_1_55_0 from trunk

Comment: I think type deduction works, so: `op = boost::bind(test_method, *user_test_case)` should be enough. Also, type of `op` should be `boost::function<void(void*)>`. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: doesn't work, still C++ Boost::bind: a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The 1st template argument of `bind` is the return type. So, it should be `void`. Or just omit it.
2. `boost::function` signature doesn't match the one of the bound function. Make it `function<void(void *)>`.
3. The functor you create should accept 1 argument, so provide the appropriate argument placeholder.
4. Finally, you can bind to the `shared_ptr`, directly.

The bottom line: `boost::function<void (void *)> op = boost::bind(test_method, user_test_case, _1);`